# Sliding images effects in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I want to change the effects of sliding images on selection of drop down menu??
Any inputs??

```
<html>
<head>
<title>jQuery Slideshow with Cycle plugin</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.cycle.all.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">


$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.content').cycle({
    fx: 'fade',
    speed: 1000,
    timeout: 2000
  });
  $("#current").click(function(){
 $("select[id$='current'] :selected").html();


    $('#content').cycle({
    fx: $(this).html(),
    speed: 1000,
    timeout: 2000
  });
  });
});
</script>
<style>
body {
  overlay: 0.7;
  background: #CCCCCC;
}
#content img {
  padding: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
}
#options {
  padding: 4px;
}
.effect {
  padding: 2px;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div align="center">
  <div class="content">
    <img src="hills.jpg" />
    <img src="lilies.jpg" />
    <img src="sunset.jpg" />
    <img src="winter.jpg" />
  </div>
  <select id="current">
<option value="fade">Fade</option>
<option value="fadeZoom">FadeZoom</option>
<option value="cover">Cover</option>
<option value="toss">Toss</option>
<option value="blindY">BlindY</option>
</select>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What effect do you want before someone can answer your question

Comment: I have added the effects which I need in the html above as drop down menu..But it seems not to be working...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a look on that fiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/qK7ds/

JS :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#current").bind('change', function(){
        var effect = $(this).val();
        alert(effect);

        $('#content').cycle({
            fx: effect,
            speed: 1000,
            timeout: 2000
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: By default the effect would be 'fade'. So I think when the dom gets loaded, we should specify that ... It worked fine by doing that.. Otherwise not..

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.content').cycle({
            fx: 'fade',
            speed: 1000,
            timeout: 2000
        });
    $("#current").bind('change', function(){
        var effect = $(this).find('option:selected').val();

        
        $('.content').cycle({
            fx: effect,
            speed: 1000,
            timeout: 2000
        });
    });
});

Comment: for sure, but like in the fiddle i've not the cycle plugin, I delete the first occurence as it was pushing an error...

Answer (score 0):

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/
This page shows you examples of change effects.

I get it now. You should change:

```
$("#current").click(function(){
```

to

```
$("#current").change(function(){
```

Comment: I know the effects available for cycle plugins.. I am trying to test these effects. So I have created an HTML page as above with a drop down box. But it is not working fine... The effects are not happening... I am just learning jquery.. so trying to fix this... Any inputs on this would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This works :)

```
$(function(){  

        var effect = '';

         $("#current").change(function(){
             effect = $(this).val();
         });

         $('.content').cycle({
            fx: effect,
            speed: 1000,
            timeout: 2000
         }); 
    });
```